# Estimate specific y value in linear multiple regression using R

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to find specific y value of fitted regression model using specific x value.

for example, in the multiple regression model like below,

> y~ aX+bZ+cW +error

**I fitted the model with data** and 
I have the result of fitted glm model like

> y = 3.142X+2.94Z+4.16W + 2.194

I'm trying to get 'y' when X is 2 and X is 5.
Is it possible in R?

Comment: It's possible in any statistical software. Just multiply. The result will also depend on Z and W. Otherwise put, quite what is the problem here? If it's entirely about seeking R code, this is off-topic here. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @NickCox Not just seeking R code. Yes, It's silly question when I try to get Y with specific X, Z, and W. However, It's about estimate Y with specific X and with'out' specific Z and W.

Comment: Unless $b$ and $c$ are both zero, June, $y$ could be *anything.* You have to make some restrictive assumptions about both $Z$ and $W$ in order to have an answerable question.

Comment: @whuber Thanks. the regression line is estimated from an actual dataset. Should I simply have to put the mean of Z and W for calculation?

Comment: I think you need to make the question much clearer. It's not clear what statistical question you have. We take it as understood that to get predictions you need to plug in coefficient estimates and whatever else applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a linear model with 3 predictors:

$y=a_0+a_1x_1+a_2x_2+a_3x_3$

```
#example with the iris dataset
mod <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data=iris)

coef(mod)
#(Intercept)  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
#1.8559975    0.6508372    0.7091320   -0.5564827
```

Now, you want to fix one predictor to a specific value and get the prediction of the model:

$x_1=C \Rightarrow y=(a_0+a_1C)+a_2x_2+a_3x_3$

Geometrically the result is a plane which crosses the y-axis at intercept $(a_0+a_1C)$.

```
#grid of Petal.Length and Petal.Width values
newdat <- expand.grid(Petal.Length=seq(min(iris$Petal.Length), max(iris$Petal.Length), length.out=1e2),
                      Petal.Width=seq(min(iris$Petal.Width), max(iris$Petal.Width), length.out=1e2))

#fix Sepal.Width to one value
newdat$Sepal.Width <- 3.0

#predict Sepal.Length
newdat$Sepal.Length <- predict(mod, newdata=newdat)

#plot the plane
library(reshape2)
plotdat <- dcast(newdat[,-3], Petal.Width~Petal.Length)

persp(x=as.numeric(names(plotdat)[-1]), 
      y=plotdat$Petal.Width, 
      z=as.matrix(plotdat[,-1]),
      xlab="Petal.Length",
      ylab="Petal.Width",
      zlab="Sepal.Length",
      theta=50, phi=10)
```

[image]

```
filled.contour(x=as.numeric(names(plotdat)[-1]), 
               y=plotdat$Petal.Width, 
               z=as.matrix(plotdat[,-1]),
               xlab="Petal.Length",
               ylab="Petal.Width",
               main="Sepal.Length")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, What I want to do have more than 3 variables, and want to just 'control' variables except X and Y. I re-upload question with the picture I found, describes exactly what I want to do...[link](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78529/how-to-make-linear-regression-model-while-control-confounding-variables)